# Check if friends and get friends list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

Hello I have a single friends table as follows:

```
Id
Sender
Recipient
```

Where sender could be the one who initiated the friendship or the same person can be the recipient. It's all stored in a single row.

How can I retrieve if "someone" is friends with "another" and get "someone" friendlist..

EDIT:
Trying to get the info from Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: Are you looking for how to get it from the database?  Can you revise your question and be more specific to what you need help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server query or stored procedure:

```
select case 
    when Sender = @SenderID then Recipient
    else Sender
end as FriendID
from Friends
where Sender = @SenderID
or Recipient = @SenderID
```

Assume you are looking for a database query?

Comment: thanks brian. however this would return 3 columns but i'm not sure how to narrow this down to just the friends of @senderid

Comment: OK, edited above.  If you only want the ID, you can use the case statement, that when the current person is the sender, get the Recipient ID, otherwise, get the Sender ID, and return it aliased as a FriendID field.

Comment: I'd like to ask one more thing regarding this subject, how can I filter out friendids from the dynamically created FriendID Column? Like add a where clause that sais WHERE FriendID = X at the end.. Now that doesn't work. Could you please share a solution? Thanks again.

Comment: You can't filter by FriendID because it's a derived column but you can use something like the case statement above within the where clause.  However, I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM Friends
WHERE Recipient = @SenderID
```